# Arduino works only after reset

Tags: arduino, nano

I have an Arduino Nano that I am using to control a couple of fans using PWM.

It seems the Arduino is "stuck" when the power is first connected, only after pressing the reset button everything starts working as it should.

This is not a breadboard, everything is soldered properly.

Any idea on how to debug this?

Thank you.

Comment: Are the fans connected directly to the nano pins or are you using an extra power supply and relays to switch them? If the are directly supplied by the nano the max A might be to much causing the Nano to stall. The reset (soft reboot) brings it then over this point.

Comment: Instead of using relays a better solution would be using MOSFETs or IGBTs (for high power). They can switch way faster and are silent. So you can control fans up to 200 W or more and the Arduino won´t get melted.

Comment: There are no relays nor MOSFETs, and the fans are connected directly to the power source with only the pwm signal sent by the Arduino using timers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `delay(300);` to the beginning of the setup function. This might solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completion I found the problem, nothing that anyone could have figured out.

I had Blu-Tack on the ISCP headers for insulation, however, it seems that Blu-Tack is conductive!

Since taking the Blu-Tack off everything is working fine. So just that anyone knows for future reference: do not mix Blu-Tack and electricity.